# Django migration failed with un-migrating m2m through field change

Tags: python, django, database-migration

I am trying to migrate one of my models back to remove this change but I am getting the traceback below.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 112, in migrate
    self.unapply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 168, in unapply_migration
    state = migration.unapply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 162, in unapply
    operation.database_backwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 206, in database_backwards
    self.database_forwards(app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 201, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 473, in alter_field
    not new_field.rel.through._meta.auto_created):
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Here is the migration

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0004_auto_20151130_2345'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameModel('OldModelName', 'NewModelName'),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='adifferentmodel',
            name='them2mfieldname',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(to='app.TheSecondModel', through='app.NewModelName', blank=True),
        ),

    ]
```

Comment: It could be a problem with your models, or a bug in Djang (see the similar traceback on [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22397)). It would help if you posted models that reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is likely in models or views. What could be the case is that you have an inner "Meta" class, somewhere with an incorrect "model" attribute.

Comment: If I comment out the AlterField it worked. Why would that matter? My app works fine on other Servers with the same code that didn't have this migration issues.

Comment: Turns out, other servers have had this issue. Not sure why commenting out the `AlterField` section would make this error go away. This was a generated migration.